# Understanding notation of the Multivariate Gaussian Distribution

Tags: notation

I have a simple notation question on the multivariate gaussian formula. I don´t get what the $T$ symbol means on the exponential part. Can anyone explain this part of the formula and the correct way to compute that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [matrix transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). The transpose is computed by swapping rows and columns. For square matrices, this corresponds to reflecting the matrix in the diagonal. For vectors, it corresponds to transforming row vectors into column vectors and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much! In this case, aren´t the x and mu variables single row matrices? That will make the transposition to have no effect right?

Comment: @PabloEstrada they are columns and become rows after transposing

Comment: @PabloEstrada: Yes, they are, and no, it won't. I've expanded the answer to treat various types of matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking of a vector as rows, now it all makes sense.